# Find duplicates in a list of arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a `List<string[]>` that I am using to hold records imported from an excel sheet of phone records.  The structure of the array is

```
[person][date][login][logout]
```

Since the phone system is old it will occasionally drop everyone and force them to login again, hence for 1 day there are 2 records, possibly more if the phones are having a bad day.

For example:

first record:

```
[Chris Iverson][03/21/2017][08:01:02][10:14:27]
```

second record:

```
[Chris Iverson][03/21/2017][10:17:03][18:00:06]
```

In the example above I have 2 records representing the 2 times I had to log into the phones. Following this example is I am looking to pull the first login of 08:01:02 and the last logout of 18:00:06 and put that into 1 record structured like this:

```
 [Chris Iverson][03/21/2017][08:01:02][18:00:06]
```

Depending on the day I may have to process 3 or more entries for each person in our group which could easily turn into 300+ records.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far? And please provide some sample arrays - it's not clear what kind of strings you have in date and login/logout items. And provide expected output. Check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Currently your question is too abstract and might be closed soon

Comment: How about iterating through the array and identifying multiple entries for the same person on the same day? That sounds good to me. Go ahead and write some code and come back when you have a more specific question. I'm not sure what you want us to do with your requirements.

Comment: use string.split to break it up to only get the name

Answer (score 2):

Arrays of strings are completely inappropriate for data manipulation. Start by converting them to objects that hold named fields with the same data:

```
class LoginRecord {
    public string Person {get;}
    public DateTime Login {get;}
    public DateTime Logout {get;}
    public LoginRecord(string person, string date, string login, string logout) {
        ... // Parse strings to make fields of appropriate types
    }
    public LoginRecord(string person, DateTime login, DateTime logout) {
        if (login.Date != logout.Date) {
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(logout));
        }
        Person = person;
        Login = login;
        Logout = logout;
    }
}
```

The constructor takes a single `date`, so the date portion of `Login` and `Logout` fields will be the same.

With a `List<LoginRecord>` in hand, you can do this:

```
var combined = list
    .GroupBy(r => new {r.Person, Date = r.Login.Date})
    .Select(g =>
        new LoginRecord(
            g.Key.Person
        ,   g.Select(r => r.Login).Min()
        ,   g.Select(r => r.Logout).Max()
        )
    ).ToList();
```

Comment: I am going to give your answer a try.  For my own education, why is a list of arrays inappropriate?

Comment: @ChrisIverson Because array elements all mean different things. This would be fine in FORTRAN or assembly, but not in C# with its wide variety of facilities to express the structure of your data in a readable way.

Comment: Even a lightweight `struct` would be better than `string[]`

Answer (score 0):

Use a Hashtable, add the string item/s as a key, prior to adding check if the key already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following array-element structure

```
[0] = person
[1] = date
[2] = login (time)
[3] = logout (time)
```

You could do something like this

```
var filtered_records = records.Where(r => r[0] == "person name" && r[1] == "date to check");
var first_login = filtered_records.Select(f => f[3]).OrderBy(o => TimeSpan.Parse(o)).FirstOrDefault();
var last_logout = filtered_records.Select(f => f[4]).OrderByDescending(o => TimeSpan.Parse(o)).FirstOrDefault();
```